# What are the caveats of upgrading an app to use Generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I'm working with an older Java application that was written for Java 1.4, before Generics were available. Since then, we have completed our upgrade to Java 6.

We are now looking into making a change to support Generics in our collections for the benefit of compile time type safety checks, and to preserve developer sanity.

Are there any caveats or gotchas we should be aware of in performing this upgrade?

Comment: See [Generics in Java Programming Language](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5/pdf/generics-tutorial.pdf). Especially paragraph 10 "Converting Legacy Code to Use Generics".

Comment: The advice in that document is certainly worth reading: there are some real gotchas especially if you are developing an API with other users rather than a self-contained application.

Comment: Thanks. I'm lucky enough that my code is for a standalone app, not an API. Others may not be so fortunate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Understand how Java generics work, and their limitations.
2. Use an IDE with good refactoring support.
3. Do it slowly and carefully.
4. Do the simple things first, and don't leap into creating complicated generic classes, etc until you know they are really required.
5. Resist the temptation to add `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` to make warnings go away.

Nothing particularly profound here ...

Comment: +1: The annotation you want to avoid having to use is `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")`  Note: Even the JDK collections compile with these warnings. :(

Comment: @Peter - yes, in some occasions the annotation is unavoidable.  But the message is that it should be used as a last resort.

Comment: "unchecked" needs to be a string in lower case.  I think most people avoid using by not knowing its there. ;)

Comment: Can you give an example of where an unchecked warning could not be avoided by using <?> and casting? I don't think I've ever seen that

Comment: @Stephen C, I am a man who has different warnings to the compiler which I tend to ignore inconsistently. ;)

Comment: @AmaDaden - that sounds like a Question.

Answer (score 1):

The most important part of the upgrade, IMHO, is to make sure that the developers working on it have a solid understanding of generics, especially with regards to passing Collections into functions and returning them from functions, as `List<Animal> <> List<Tiger>` , etc.  You should always be able to put in generics, even if you are using the generic Object or ? placeholders.

The other thing that will make the conversion go smooth/not is code dependent, that you have collections that contain a single type, that there aren't mixed objects that force the ? or Object 'catch-alls.'  This can be fairly common, especially with Maps.

If you use any underlying libraries, Hibernate, etc, you can run into limitations there if the underlying library does not support generics.  In that case, you'll either have to leak the library code through, or wrap the objects (not recommended).

Change the pieces that make sense, leave the pieces that don't, and do it in stages so that you can always roll back a piece if you run into a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Stephen is dead on, but I would add a few tips.

1) Since Generics are compile time only they are useless in a few places like reflection and storing objects in the session (if this is a web project). I don't know any clean way to deal with this. I recommend just declaring anything that comes out of it as `<?>` and just dealing with the type checking.

2) This is one that has burned me in the past. In method definitions use `List<? extends Shape>` and not `List<Shape>`. If you have a `Circle` type that is a child of `Shape` then `List<Circle>` can't be passed in to `List<Shape>` but it can be passed in to `List<? extends Shape>`. This seems minor but for me it came up very suddenly and required lots of additional changes to classes I thought were done.

3) I don't think that you EVER need to suppress generics warnings since you can always turn a `List` in to a `List<?>` and get rid of them. However I recommend that you do not do this unless that part of the code can't use generics (see my first point). It's better to have warnings you plan to fix then bad fixes you plan to improve since you will likely never improve them and the warnings will be staring you in the face every time you look at your project.